# have to bind array param everytime in loop with php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a loop in which I have to do multiple inserts to the database, it appears that I have to bind the data array every time I get new data and the data changes. I though we could bind once and insert multiple times.

Further research has shown that PDO might be better suited to this task, but I'm curious why its like this with mysqli, and if there is a way to bind array once and execute multiple times.

See comments in code for more detail.

```
<?php
//usual db stuff
$DBhost = 'localhost';
$DBname = 'test';
$DBuser = '';
$DBpass = '';

//error reporting for mysql
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

//connect to database
$conn = new mysqli($DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpass, $DBname);

//prepare this is a dummy table in a dummy database
//actual table is quite complicated
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `users` (`fname`,`lname`,`city`) VALUES(?,?,?)');

//create a variable to store the data
// so we can bind it before going further
$data=array_fill(0,3,'');
//bind params use array expansion
$stmt->bind_param('sss', ...$data);

//this part runs in a loop
// mock loop for just to show idea
for($i=0;$i<1;$i++)
{
    //get the data
    $data = get_data();
    //already binded $data before the loop
    //so execute this should insert the data just returned
    //except this doesnt, it inserts blanks
    //it acts as if the data still has the blank array from line 20
    $stmt->execute();

    //bind it again
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', ...$data);
    //execute
    //this inserts the data
    $stmt->execute();
}

//mock function to return data the actual function 
//returns a multi dimesional array for multiple tables
function get_data()
{
    return(array("dinesh","chand","nadi"));
}
```

any help or ideas highly appreciated

Comment: You only need to `bind_param` once. You are doing it multiple times. After a bind, just change the value of the variable ($data) you bound to the parameter. And you're calling `$stmt->execute()` twice. Remove the first one.

Comment: @Karlo Kokkak I guess you skipped over all the comments in the code, without binding it every time inserts the data as if the array was a blank array, the first one is where it inserts blank data even though $data has changed, the second one executed after binding again does insert the data, so removing the first one and the bind inside the for loop it only inserts blank data.

Comment: Just do the changes I suggested. See if it works.

Comment: Remove the first bind_param as well.

Comment: @Karlo Kokkak I have already tried those changes, and more, if I  remove the first bind that leaves me with the bind in the loop which means the bind will run every time the loop is run, which is what I am trying to aviod

Comment: pastebin the updated code pls.

Comment: Insert `$stmt->execute()` above for loop. And 0, 3 are integers.

Comment: @Karlo Kokkak this https://pastebin.com/VShED0d3 inserts blank data while this https://pastebin.com/YCYc74Am works but is not ideal as the binding is done multiple times

Comment: Array, in this case, in bind_param, won't bind by reference. I wonder why? Maybe because each element aren't considered a regular variable that you can referenced to.

Comment: Replace your `$data` variable with three separate variables that are not an array so you will only bind once.

Comment: @Karlo Kokkak I'm guessing using an array is not possible, oh well... In the actual code the number of variables from (20 to 50) keep changing, even the sql for prepare has to be created automatically, so not feasible to replace with individual variables, the code here is just to show the issue

Comment: If you prefer array then you will have to `bind_param()` each time array variable value changes.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `$stmt->execute();` for the first time, inside the for loop, you are executing what you have bind before starting the `for loop`. So what you have to do is.

1. Bind what you want `$stmt->bind_param('sss', ...$data);`
2. Then execute `$stmt->execute();`

In your code above, first, remove `$stmt->execute();` (first inside the `for loop`). Then add it after you bind the parameters for the first time(above the `for loop`). As follows,

**Note:** What I have changed are marked with `########`

```
<?php
//usual db stuff
$DBhost = 'localhost';
$DBname = 'test';
$DBuser = '';
$DBpass = '';

//error reporting for mysql
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

//connect to database
$conn = new mysqli($DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpass, $DBname);

//prepare this is a dummy table in a dummy database
//actual table is quite complicated
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `users` (`fname`,`lname`,`city`) VALUES(?,?,?)');

//create a variable to store the data
// so we can bind it before going further
$data=array_fill(0,3,'');
//bind params use array expansion
$stmt->bind_param('sss', ...$data);

$stmt->execute(); //########

//this part runs in a loop
// mock loop for just to show idea
for($i=0;$i<1;$i++)
{
    //get the data
    $data = get_data();
    //already binded $data before the loop
    //so execute this should insert the data just returned
    //except this doesnt, it inserts blanks
    //it acts as if the data still has the blank array from line 20
    //$stmt->execute(); ########

    //bind it again
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', ...$data);
    //execute
    //this inserts the data
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Im sorry but how will putting the execute above the loop insert the data when data is only truly available inside the loop? you still have bind inside the loop so it will bind as many times as the loop runs, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: In your code, you have used `$stmt->bind_param('sss', ...$data);` , before the for loop. So it will bind what is inside `$data`. After that, you bind the data and execute it. when you `$stmt->execute();` your data gets inserted into your database.